# how to show google , my website is fair use downloading site befor removing from results?

Tags: google, copyright, dmca

My website is for downloading software and is limited access for only users (by IP limitation) and there is no relation between this country and US for copyright policy (Circular 38a of the US Copyright Office). So it's non copyright country!

I'm looking for a way to show Google its fair use, so it doesn't remove it for Dmca Reports in results! Is there a way?

Comment: "Fair use" is an exception from copy restrictions that is rooted in US copyright law.  I don't think that your country is one of the fair use exemptions.  It sounds more like a jurisdictional issue to me.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the copyright law is in your country, it matters what the copyright law is in Google's country (the United States). Google's job isn't to enforce the laws of your country, their job is to abide by the laws of their country.

Comment: when this content only available in my country , so why it matters for google and US Law`s ?

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the law in your country, Google's policies as they apply to DCMA legislation in the United States (where Google are headquartered) mean that regardless of whether it is legal for someone in your country to ignore copyright restrictions on what you offer, Google are well within their rights to remove your website's listing from their search results worldwide if requested by the copyright owner in the USA.

Because of this, you have probably been flagged by Google as a "repeat offender".

https://support.google.com/legal/answer/11625144

Comment: pages and accessing to site is only allow for google bots and my country ( none copyright country ) are you sure google needs to remove it from search results?

Comment: @Amirofficial That your country refuses to recognise international copyright laws is irrelevant. Google operates in countries that do and the laws of those countries allow the legal owners of that copyright to compel Google to deny free advertising to anyone who facilitate the theft of their legal property, regardless of whether that is a crime in the jurisdiction of the country where that website is hosted.